# How to prevent tqdm from printing progress bar in newline while multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, tqdm

I was messing around with the tqdm module and wanted to run simultaneous progress bars, so i made Thread objects as below

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    for i in tqdm(range(20)):
        time.sleep(0.1)

def func2():
    for j in tqdm(range(20)):
        time.sleep(0.3)

t1 = Thread(target=func1)
t2 = Thread(target=func2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t2.join()
t1.join()

print('Completed')
```

The output starts with[image: Starting ouput]

But when thread t2 ends, it exchanges position with the bar display of t1
and t1 runs till it ends.

I don't want the bars to exchange positions

I tried interchanging the positions of lines of starting and joining of threads but it leads to re printing of t1 bar once t2 finishes like this [image: messed up output]

To analyse these problems i would recommend trying running these codes for yourself.

Can someone tell me why these both things are happening and how to fix it ?

Comment: Are you using a windows machine?

Comment: yes, my operating system is windows 11 and the code has been run in VS Code.

Comment: Check out the [common issues and FAQ](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#table-of-contents) and search for `colorama`: "Windows: additionally may require the Python module colorama to ensure nested bars stay within their respective lines."

Comment: You can also try setting the position for each: `for i in tqdm(range(20), position=0)` and `for j in tqdm(range(20), position=1):`

Comment: colorama was installed as a dependency when i used pip to install tqdm. I tried passing the position parameters but still the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be updating all bars in separate thread (using `Queue` to get which bar should be updated next):

```py
import time
import queue
from tqdm import tqdm
from threading import Thread

bars_queue = queue.Queue()


def func1():
    for i in range(20):
        bars_queue.put_nowait(0)  # update bar 0
        time.sleep(0.1)


def func2():
    for j in range(20):
        bars_queue.put_nowait(1)  # update bar 1
        time.sleep(0.3)


def bars_handler():
    bars = [tqdm(total=20, position=i) for i in range(2)]
    while True:
        i = bars_queue.get()  # which bar should I update next?
        bars[i].update()
        bars[i].refresh()


bars_thread = Thread(target=bars_handler, daemon=True) # daemon=True so we don't have to use .join()
bars_thread.start()

t1 = Thread(target=func1)
t2 = Thread(target=func2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t2.join()
t1.join()

print("{}Completed".format("\n" * 2))
```

Prints correctly the bars:

```
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 10.09it/s]
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:05<00:00,  3.33it/s]
Completed
```

Comment: Can we make the bars_thread non-daemonic ? The documentation of the threading module says as a note ```Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.```.